# MediaController onPlaybackStateChanged never called in Android

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, mediacontroller

I am trying check the playback state of `MediaController` in android. but i get **null** response all the time. I am using `Mediaplayer` to play music and `MediaController` for controls.

Answer (score 0):

Add snippets of your code, so we could understand your problem